# Two-group Probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had this question on a test a few days ago, and when I got the test back, this question was marked wrong:

> In a group of 500 people, 60% of them are female.  In this same group, 10% of the people speak Spanish.  What percent of the females in the group speak Spanish?
>
> > [A] 60%
> >     [B] 16%
> >     [C] 10%
> >     [D] 6%
> >     [E] not enough information given

I said the answer was E, was this incorrect, and if so, why?

(The reason I chose this is the 60% of the group that is female could be a different group than than the 10% Spanish-speaking group, and the groups may not overlap -- assuming that the groups are not evenly scattered around the group of people.)

I have seen these types of questions before, and previously I would have just multiplied 60% by 10% to get 6% as the answer, but I thought about it, and I noticed that this could be the case.  (I like finding exceptions and things like this in math problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are right that not enough information has been given to determine.  Since $60$% of $500$ people are female, that is $300$ females and $200$ non females.  Out of the $500$ total people in the group, $10$% speak Spanish.  We don't know which $10$% and that is only $50$ people so it is possible that all $50$ Spanish speaking people in the group are not even females.  However, if all the Spanish speaking people are female, we know that it can be no more than $50/300$ = $16.67$% so we know right away that answer A is wrong so it must be B, C, D, or E.